# get checked checkboxes from database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am looknig to seek a way to get the tick boxes checked if they are assigned to the category in the database.

```
<?php 


try{
    // Selecting entire row from cat_list table
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT cat_id, cat_title FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
    $category = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>
<div id="checkboxlist" >
<?php
    foreach($category as $cat){ 
?>

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"];  ?>" <?php echo ($cat['cat_id'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

<?php
}
```

So when I create the post I select from the available categories which are displayed as an array, the code above is taken from my edit post form so I want it retrieve the categories I assigned to it and tick the boxes.

I have 3 tables:

```
doc_list (Stores documents)
cat_list (Stores Categories)
cat_doc_link_table (stores the doc_id & cat_id from the previous two tables)
```

Here are how they are formed:

```
CREATE TABLE `cat_doc_link_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link_doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `cat_list` (
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_title` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `cat_color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cat_icon` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 AUTO_INCREMENT=66 ;

CREATE TABLE `doc_list` (
`doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_content` text NOT NULL,
  `doc_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 AUTO_INCREMENT=295 ;
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov so I can insert the post into the database including the categories I select (there is a join table which takes the id form the post and the id from the category) and stores the values that way. The idea is for me to be able to go back to the post and it already have the checkboxes ticked for which I assigned it to.

Comment: That is perfectly fine, but I can't seem to figure what is wrong with the code you posted and what problems you are facing with it? Please, note that questions without proper problem statements end up closed and do not fit well in the SO spirit as per FAQ (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov there is an issue with it because what I am trying to do does not work?

Comment: See the FAQ I linked, this type of questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: @reggaeguitar It isn't showing the ticks in the boxes from the categories they are associated to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the selected cat_id's in an array(). then use in_array() to check.

```
// query your db to return an array of cat_id's for the specified post.
$cats_array = array('123', '124', '156');

foreach($category as $cat){
 // compare
 if(in_array($cat['cat_id'], $cats_array)) { 
   // cat checked
 }else{
   // not checked
 }
}
```

Comment: could you use my code from above to show me an example?

Comment: I have tried to do the above by there must be an error as I am faced with a white screen

Comment: you need to query the table that has the postid and catid, take those results and create an array of just the catid's for the specified post. Once you have the array you add the in_array conditional inside the foreach statement.

Comment: But would that no conflict with me taking  data from the category table above also?

Comment: no it would not. As I understand your table scheme you are storing post_id and cat_id in another table for each checked category. "select cat_id from table where post_id = '$post_id'" ... take the returned cat_id and add it to $cats_array().

Comment: I am really really confused - I really do not know why I am unable to understand such a  simple thing? And yes I am storing the post_id and also the cat_id and I match them up ad they are stored as a row in the join table

Comment: am I getting closer: `    <?php
    "SELECT cat_id FROM cat_doc_link_table WHERE doc_id = '$doc_id'"
        foreach($category as $cat){ 
    ?>
                
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"];  ?>" name="cat_no[]" id="box1"> <?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>
        
    <?php
    }
    ?>`

Comment: update your original post with table names and structures. Then I can help further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78830/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-brian).